# Selecting Current Day in Seleniunm

Tags: python, datetime, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open a calendar and select only the current day of the specific calendar (month, and using selenium).

So far, I have this:

```
#Click on calendar and open the same

self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='searchform']/div/div/div[2]/div/input")
self.search_field.click()

# Get current day

current_date = date.today()
today_day = current_date.day
print today_day
```

Now that I've got the "current day," how would I select that "current day" within the given calendar?

---

[Edit]

Calendar HTML

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 151px; left: 222.5px; z-index: 1; display: block;">
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-year="2015" data-month="10" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<td class=" " data-year="2015" data-month="10" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over ui-datepicker-today" data-year="2015" data-month="10" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">24</a>
</td>
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-  state-disabled ">
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is not enough information. Provide the HTML representation of the input and a screenshot of the calendar. Thanks.

Comment: Some calendars allow you to manually enter the date in certain formats like DD/MM/YYYY, see if you can do that, it will reduce the overhead of UI interaction.

Comment: Can you show the DOM for the calendar?